# Where are the memory leaks?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, multidimensional-array

I have this piece of code and for some reason it creates 6 memory leaks and I can't figure out where.

```
    Lemon::Lemon()
{
    this->nrOf=0;
    int x=10;
    this->matrix=new int*[x];
    this->lines=new string[x];
    for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i) 
        this->matrix[i] = new int[x];
    for(int i=0;i<x;++i)
        for(int j=0;j<x;++j)
            this->matrix[i][j]=-1;

}
Lemon::Lemon(int n)
{
    this->x=this->nrOf;
    this->matrix=new int*[x];
    this->lines=new string[x];
    for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i) 
        this->matrix[i] = new int[x];
    for(int i=0;i<x;++i)
        for(int j=0;j<x;++j)
            this->matrix[i][j]=-1;
}

Lemon::~Lemon()
{
    for(int i=0;i<this->nrOf;i++)
    {
        delete []this->matrix[i];
    }
    delete []this->matrix;
    delete []this->lines;
}
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Well the code above is not used so it can't leak. Show us how you use it (and the class definition) and then we can explain how it leaks. Don't forget the rule of three.

Comment: Your code violates the [rule of three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/). You'll get a lot more memory leaks and undefined behavior once you start copying lemons.

Comment: How many leaks does it have without the second constructor (`Lemon(int)`)? How many does it have with `lines` but no `matrix`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this point:

```
this->x=this->nrOf;
```

nrOf has not been initialised - you have undefined behavior.

And possibly you would benefit from using std::vector.

Comment: I would possibly, but I'm just trying to get more familiar with multidimensional arrays.

Comment: @ogward You can use vector to implement multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: thanks for the tip, I need to get more familiar with vectors. Everyone keeps telling me to use them.

Answer (score 1):

The default constructor initializes nrOf with 0, but you allocate a matrix of 10x10. Which means the destructor will not run the for loop, since nrOf is 0.

BTW, you don't have to prefix everything with this. It kinda makes the code harder to read. You should use this only to eliminate ambiguity.

Comment: If you find yourself needing to use `this->` to remove ambiguity you can probably rename some of the variables instead and get a better way to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: I agree with that. I don't think I use this except for passing a pointer to the current object to some function.

Answer (score 1):

You don't set `nrOf` to the number of allocated matrix rows in either constructor.

Comment: I have a readFromfile function and when the first number of the textfile is read i initiate nrOf to that number.

Comment: That may be so, but you allocate memory without recording how much you've allocated. Are you engaging in some sort of gamble as to whether the first number in the file happens to match your allocation? You seem to be losing...  :-)

Comment: ok I've manged to remove all my memory leaks by moving my read from file function into my constructor, but that is really ugly...Is there any other way I can do it? I want to read the first line of the file then create my two arrays and then send the info from the files into the arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Try this as your *only* constructor

```
Lemon::Lemon(int n = 10)  // default constructor
{
  nrOf = n;

  matrix = new int*[nrOf];
  lines = new string[nrOf];

  for (int i = 0; i < nrOf; ++i) 
    matrix[i] = new int[nrOf];

  for(int i=0; i<nrOf; ++i)
    for(int j=0; j<nrOf; ++j)
        this->matrix[i][j] = -1;
}
```

Comment: the problem is that the size of the matrix is read from a text file.

Comment: @ogward: and so...? You'll still need to construct one of these.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have both a member variable `int x` (used in `Lemon::Lemon(int n)`) as well as a local variable `int x` in `Lemon::Lemon()`.  Also, you do not consistently set `nrOf` in your constructors.

Answer (score 0):

**Note 1:**

Every new-expression in your code is possible memory leak because your code is awfully exception unsafe: if any of your `new` expressions throw an exception all your already new-allocated storage is leaked.

**Note 2:**

Your first constructor does not semantically match your destructor (even if we assume that everything goes fine without throwing): constructor assigns zero value to `this->nrOf` but allocates 10 elements of `this->matrix` array and assign allocated array to each element BUT destructor expects `this->nrOf` elements of `this->matrix` (arrays) to delete so 0 elements is deleted and thus 10 elements are leaked.

**Side note:** your `this->x` (that exists according to second constructor) is not initialized by first constructor.

**Note 3:**

Your second constructor is simply corrupt: you never initialize `this->nrOf` variable but you use it like it contains something valid.

**ADD:**

Good advise here would be: never use arrays and `new`/`new[]`/`delete`/`delete[]` expressions. Use `std::vector` in your situation instead. This way you may never care about memory leaks, exception safety, etc.

Your `matrix` would look like this:

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > matrix;
....................
....................
n = 10;
m = 20;
matrix.resize(n);

for( size_t j = 0; j < n; ++j )
{
    matrix[j].resize(m);

    for( size_t k = 0; k < m; ++k )
    {
        matrix[j][k] = j+k;
    }
}
```